# Regular Expression to use in Split function

Tags: python, regex, perl

I am new to regular expressions. Can someone help me in the regular expression to split the below data. I tried with  regex `\\\\,` but its splitting on comma inside the braces and outside also. Commas inside the braces `[]` should be skipped.

Input

```
[111,212],[231,543],[231,423]
```

Output

```
[111,212]
[231,543]
[231,423]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that there are no spaces around the commas, the split regex you want is `,(?=\[)`

Example in JavaScript:

```
$ node
> re = /,(?=\[)/
/,(?=\[)/
> "[111,212],[231,543],[231,423]".split(re)
[ '[111,212]', '[231,543]', '[231,423]' ]
```

Example in Python:

```
$ python
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r',(?=\[)')
>>> re.split(r, "[111,212],[231,543],[231,423]")
['[111,212]', '[231,543]', '[231,423]']
```

Explanation: `,(?=\[)` means a comma that is followed by a left bracket. The expression in `(?=)` is a *positive lookahead* and is not consumed. The only thing used as a splitter is the comma itself. But the only commas we split on are the ones followed by the left brackets. We don't split on the other commas.

Comment: Thanks. I need the regex in perl or python.

Comment: No problem. Edited the answer with the Python solution for you.

Answer (score 2):

In Python (*based off the comment you left*), match all vs. `split`ting the string:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '[111,212],[231,543],[231,423]'
>>> m = re.findall(r'\[[^]]*]', s)
>>> for x in m:
...     print x

[111,212]
[231,543]
[231,423]
```

Comment: Nice job recognizing the x-y problem here! Question asked for split but was really just about extracting the lists.

Answer (score 1):

You need to match commas that are followed by a square bracket or that are not followed by a digit. For that you use the lookahead operators. `,(?=\[)` or `,(?!\d)` will both work for you. The contents of the parentheses are not going to be part of the match, only comma will.

Comment: The first one failed and the second one splitted all the commas.(inside the braces also)

Comment: @HariKrishna - Both should work if you don't have spaces: https://regex101.com/r/nJ2eK6/3

Answer (score 0):

If you know there are no spaces you can use `,\B`.
`\B` is checks that that comma comes before a non alphanumeric character, like `[` (the opposite of `\b`).

If you can have space, you can use `\s*,\s*+\B`
(Perl only, Python `re` doesn't support `*+`).
`\s*+` is a possessive quantifier to make sure all spaces are consumed.

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/nJ2eK6/1

Either way, I'd go with Hwnd's answer - it allows you to capture the two number, which you probably want anyway.